# What should I think of a company that never handed contracts to their employees until I started to ask for one?

Tags: contracts, mexico

I recently started working for a company. Since the first day I asked for a *contract* to sign, and HR told to wait a bit. A month passed and I discovered *nobody* had a contract, even those that have been working there for one year.

Should I be worried about something?

Country: Mexico.

Comment: Are you an employee or an independent contractor?

Comment: @WillemRenzema Don't really know, but I guess I'm an independent contractor since its and ad agency.

Comment: It is not my fault if you do not express yourself clearly, and it is impossible for me (or anyone else) to asses your knowledge of legal terms, specially if you misuse the terms and show to be quite naive about the circunstances of your own employment (do you **guess** what kind of contract **you** have?). In any case, if you do not like my informations, you can have your money back.

Comment: Being helpful does not mean tolerating your lack of modals.

Comment: @SJuan76 Please stop commenting if it's not related to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @dawn It is related to the question. There is a world of difference between the employment terms of an employee vs. a contractor.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I have no specific knowledge of Mexico, but contractor or not, I'd be looking to run a mile from any job where this was the case.

It'd make it way to easy for them to do all sorts of bad things that could affect you - fire you on the spot without any notice period, reduce your salary without explanation, not pay your salary without explanation, refuse to acknowledge you've ever worked there (which could lead to some unpleasant tax situations), change your job role / title without any notice, refuse to give any references to future employers, etc.

Unless those are all risks you're willing to take, then look to get out ASAP.